# Possible error in nltk.tag.perceptron.py

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger, perceptron

I wonder if there are some errors on variables in [perceptron.py](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/perceptron.html#PerceptronTagger).

```
class PerceptronTagger(TaggerI):

'''
Greedy Averaged Perceptron tagger, as implemented by Matthew Honnibal.
See more implementation details here:
    http://spacy.io/blog/part-of-speech-POS-tagger-in-python/

>>> from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger

Train the model 

>>> tagger = PerceptronTagger(load=False)

>>> tagger.train([[('today','NN'),('is','VBZ'),('good','JJ'),('day','NN')],
... [('yes','NNS'),('it','PRP'),('beautiful','JJ')]])

>>> tagger.tag(['today','is','a','beautiful','day'])
[('today', 'NN'), ('is', 'PRP'), ('a', 'PRP'), ('beautiful', 'JJ'), ('day', 'NN')]

Use the pretrain model (the default constructor) 

>>> pretrain = PerceptronTagger()

>>> pretrain.tag('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split())
[('The', 'DT'), ('quick', 'JJ'), ('brown', 'NN'), ('fox', 'NN'), ('jumps', 'VBZ'), ('over', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('lazy', 'JJ'), ('dog', 'NN')]

>>> pretrain.tag("The red cat".split())
[('The', 'DT'), ('red', 'JJ'), ('cat', 'NN')]
'''

START = ['-START-', '-START2-']
END = ['-END-', '-END2-']

def __init__(self, load=True):
    '''
    :param load: Load the pickled model upon instantiation.
    '''
    self.model = AveragedPerceptron()
    self.tagdict = {}
    self.classes = set()
    if load:
        AP_MODEL_LOC = 'file:'+str(find('taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/'+PICKLE))
        self.load(AP_MODEL_LOC)

def _get_features(self, i, word, context, prev, prev2):
    '''Map tokens into a feature representation, implemented as a
    {hashable: float} dict. If the features change, a new model must be
    trained.
    '''
    def add(name, *args):
        features[' '.join((name,) + tuple(args))] += 1

    i += len(self.START)
    features = defaultdict(int)
    # It's useful to have a constant feature, which acts sort of like a prior
    add('bias')
    add('i suffix', word[-3:])
    add('i pref1', word[0])
    add('i-1 tag', prev)
    add('i-2 tag', prev2)
    add('i tag+i-2 tag', prev, prev2) # SHOULDN'T IT BE 'i-1 tag+i-2 tag'?
    add('i word', context[i])
    add('i-1 tag+i word', prev, context[i])
    add('i-1 word', context[i-1])
    add('i-1 suffix', context[i-1][-3:])
    add('i-2 word', context[i-2])
    add('i+1 word', context[i+1])
    add('i+1 suffix', context[i+1][-3:])
    add('i+2 word', context[i+2])
    return features
```

`add('i-1 tag', prev)`,`add('i-2 tag', prev2)` shows `prev` indicates prevous tag, and `prev2` indicates the tag before previous tag. OK. then,

- `add('i tag+i-2 tag', prev, prev2)` WHY `prev` here is set to indcate current tag (i tag)?

Related to this, there's another question in its method `train`:

```
def train(self, sentences, save_loc=None, nr_iter=5):
    '''Train a model from sentences, and save it at ``save_loc``. ``nr_iter``
    controls the number of Perceptron training iterations.

    :param sentences: A list of (words, tags) tuples.
    :param save_loc: If not ``None``, saves a pickled model in this location.
    :param nr_iter: Number of training iterations.
    '''
    self._make_tagdict(sentences)
    self.model.classes = self.classes
    for iter_ in range(nr_iter):
        c = 0
        n = 0
        for sentence  in sentences:
            words = [word for word,tag in sentence]
            tags  = [tag for word,tag in sentence]

            prev, prev2 = self.START
            context = self.START + [self.normalize(w) for w in words] \
                                                                + self.END
            for i, word in enumerate(words):
                guess = self.tagdict.get(word)
                if not guess:
                    feats = self._get_features(i, word, context, prev, prev2)
                    guess = self.model.predict(feats)
                    self.model.update(tags[i], guess, feats)
                prev2 = prev    # prev = prev2?
                prev = guess    # prev2 = guess?
                c += guess == tags[i]
                n += 1
        random.shuffle(sentences)
        logging.info("Iter {0}: {1}/{2}={3}".format(iter_, c, n, _pc(c, n)))
    self.model.average_weights()
    # Pickle as a binary file
    if save_loc is not None:
        with open(save_loc, 'wb') as fout:
            pickle.dump((self.model.weights, self.tagdict, self.classes), fout, -1)
```

- I don't understand why `prev2 = prev`, `prev = guess` is used in the inner loop.

Codes above says that `guess` indicates the estimated tag of current word, `prev2` is given the guessed tag for the next loop, `prev` is given previous tag in the current loop. However, I think it should be modified as follow because the tag sequence is `prev, prev2, guess`.

```
prev = prev2
prev2 = guess
```

Suppose we have a word sequence of `['-START-', '-START2-', 'T0', 'T1', 'T2', '-END-', '-END2-']`,
then shouldn't it the varables be in the process of word iteration like this?

```
      prev      prev2
i=0   -START-   -START2-
i=1   -START2-  T0
i=2   T0        T1
i=3   T1        T2
...
```

Am I wrong?

`perceptron.py` is included in NLTK, so that it's worth checking if there's an error for common use.